# Why am I getting TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

```
#Imports#
import sys
sys.path.append("F:\A2\Computing\Comp 4\Python34\Lib\site-packages")

from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#Main Code#


class GUIImage(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, master, *pargs)

        self.image = Image.open("F:\A2\Computing\Comp 4\Code\main.jpg")
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

        self.frames={}

        for F in(mainMenuGUI,addUserGUI,delUserGUI,visitorGUI,prechkGUI,userManual):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[Frames] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)


class mainMenuGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init(self,parent)
        mainMenuGUI = GUIImage(App)
        mainMenuGUI.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        MMText = Label(self, text ="Main Menu",bg ="#FD7F17", font = ("Arial Black",18)).place(relx=.40, rely=.05)
        MMButton1= Button(self, text = "Add User", fg = "white",bg = "dark grey", command = lambda:controller.show_frame(addUserGUI),height = "1", width ="10", font = ("Arial Black",14)).place(relx =.38 , rely=.14)
        MMButton2= Button(self, text = "Delete User", fg = "white",bg = "dark grey", command = lambda:controller.show_frame(delUserGUI),height = "1", width ="10", font = ("Arial Black",14)).place(relx =.38 , rely=.28)
        MMButton3= Button(self, text = "Add Visitor", fg = "white",bg = "dark grey", command = lambda:controller.show_frame(VisitorGUI),height = "1", width ="10", font = ("Arial Black",14)).place(relx =.38 , rely=.42)
        MMButton4= Button(self, text = "Premises Check", fg = "white",bg = "dark grey", command =   lambda:controller.show_frame(prechkGUI) ,height = "1", width ="14", font = ("Arial Black",14)).place(relx =.32 , rely=.56)
        MMButton5= Button(self, text = "Vehicle Check", fg = "white",bg = "dark grey", command = "navVehChe",height = "1", width ="14", font = ("Arial Black",14)).place(relx =.32 , rely=.70)
        MMButton6= Button(self, text = "User Manual", fg = "white",bg = "dark grey", command =  lambda:controller.show_frame(userManual),height = "1", width ="10", font = ("Arial Black",14)).place(relx =.38 , rely=.84)

App = GUIImage()
App.mainloop()
```

Currently, I get the error

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'
```

when it is ran, I have a vague idea of why it doesn't work.

Comment: The a complete traceback would be nice so we don't have to guess where the exception originates.

Comment: Look at `GUIImage.__init__()`; you didn't provide that required argument there.

Comment: How could you look at the line in the traceback where you were doing exactly what the error message says (not passing the required positional argument), and **not** be able to solve it?

Comment: Sorry, the Traceback was :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\A2\Computing\Comp 4\Code\GUItemplate.py", line 71, in <module>
    App = GUIImage()

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these three lines of code:

```
class GUIImage(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
```

and...

```
App = GUIImage()
```

The error message clearly says this:

> __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'

Clearly, `__init__` requires an argument named 'master', which you aren't providing when you create `App`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been trying to figure this out, but I just can't get to the bottom of what is necessary as an argument here. I would be very grateful for anymore help you can provide.

Comment: @KryptoNyte Look where you use `master` in that method. And then try to explain why. Maybe looking up what the called method expects as arguments helps.

Comment: @KryptoNyte: you have specifically said that `GUIImage` requires the parameter `master`. Do you not see that word in the definition of `__init__`?